# Financial implications of purchasing a first home?

Tags: united-states, taxes, tax-deduction, home-ownership, first-time-home-buyer

My girlfriend and I bought our first home and I'm wondering what finance topics this touches on?

Some relevant info might be:

- We're in Vermont
- We aren't married
- We bought the house in late June
- Some of the downpayment was gifted from family
- Some of the downpayment was liquidated investment funds

Comment: I voted to close because this is way too broad a question. You are expecting an answer that touches on home ownership, taxes, entering a serious financial transaction with a person you are dating. The only short answer is that all of this should have been resolved in the months before you signed the contract to make the offer, let alone before you actually settled.

Comment: @mhoran_psprep - In general, I agree. For questions like this, I hold out a bit of hope a few answers are so useful, they help the OP and others. And, perhaps the question gets edited a bit to tighten it up. Since my close *vote* is a full closure, I'm leaving this for now.

Answer (score 2):

Congrats!

Make sure you nail down NOW what happens to the house should you eventually separate. I know lots of unmarried couples who have stayed together for decades and look likely to do so for life; I've also seen some marriages break up that I wouldn't have expected to. Better to have this discussion NOW.

Beyond that: Main immediate implications are that you have new costs (taxes, utilities, maintenance) and new tax issues (mortgage interest and property tax deductability) and you're going to have to figure out how to allocate those between you (if there is a between; not sure whether unmarried couples can file jointly these days).

Comment: An unmarried couple can't file jointly, they need to allocate the deductions.

Comment: @JoeTaxpayer: Expected so, but I keep hoping they'll drop the word "marriage" from the lawbooks entirely...

Comment: It's a slippery slope. Married couples enjoy the unlimited gifting or inheritance. Not sure how the code would be adjusted if 'marriage' were removed from code altogether.